# picasa web albums poor image quality?

Tags: mac, iphoto, picasa, jpeg

Did anyone else notice the picture quality degrade after uploading to picasa web albums from Picasa 3.5 Mac?

I uploaded them in the original setting which is 1600 by 1200 and did selected the option to not compress jpg quality. On picasa web albums however, I notice that the colors look faded and the picture are a bit grainy.

Anyone have the same problems? Any alternatives to an album sharing site with easy upload from picasa or iphoto?

Comment: Be advised, this question most likely to be closed. Work quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have the same. The online version is almost too sharp and a little faded. The local version is richer and 'smoother' detail. I checked in Adobe bridge and it agrees with the local Picasa version. Something is happening in the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

Check these settings when you upload photo's

http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=113848

Comment: those setting are set correctly, the thumnails in the actual website actually seem degraded

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not occurs during upload.  The problem mainly occurs during real-time resize for the web page display.  Google resizes the picture in real-time to fit the space available in the web page, to ensure the minimum data is transfered during viewing.  Unfortunately, the resize algorithm sets the JPEG quality level very low, so the resulting picture lose a lot of detail.

I don't think this is configurable.

I recommend viewing the picture full screen in the slide show mode, which provide more details, because the resolution is higher.